# Joint Probability Density Function P(Y < 1/2) integration

Tags: probability, density-function

*Let X and Y be continuous random variables that have the following joint probability density function:*
$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
3y\ ,\ 0\le x\le y \le1 \\
0 \ \ \  ,\ elsewhere 
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to find $P(Y < 1/2)$ I'm having difficulty understanding the precise steps, and because 1/2 is a constant, I'm wondering if I'm supposed to find this probability via $\int_0^{1/2}3y \ dy$, $\int_x^{1/2}\int_0^y 3y \ dy$, or some other limits and ordering here. Every resource, including online, textbook, and accompanying exercises includes another variable in the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

$f_Y(y)=\int f_{X,Y} (x,y)dx=3y^{2}$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$. Hence $P(Y<\frac 1  2)=\int_0^{\frac 1  2} 3y^{2}dy=\frac 1 8$.

Comment: I see I was skipping an entire step from integrating the marginal probability of Y on the range listed, or getting lost in the algebra and missing bits and pieces.